In Windows Application Packaging Project, WebView2 intialized in one process is not allowing the other process to intialize the webview2
We've a windows application project with WinForms running in one process and UWP running in another process. We've a use case to initialize webview2 in Winforms (Microsoft.Web.Webview2 1.0.2535.41). But after initializing in Winforms, when we try to initialize Webview2 in UWP (Microsoft.UI.XAML 2.8.2) using WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async, the underlying CoreWebView2 is always null. This is happening the other way around as well when WebView2 is actively running in UWP process, trying to intialize a webview2 in WinForm's process is returning the CoreWebView2 as null. Only when the webview2 is destroyed in one process, the other process is allowing to intialize the webview2 in its process. Why is it so? Any thoughts?
Microsoft Edge Webview2 runtime installed:- 128.0.2739.42
